# concatenate to last element in list in java

Tags: java, list, concatenation

How to concatenate to last element in a list?

```
List<String> x = {cow, cat, dog}; //explanation purpose
```

I want to concatenate "dog" as "dogs" if a if-statement is triggered.

Comment: Get the last element: `x.get(x.size() - 1);`, but note that strings are immutable objects, you cannot change them - but you can replace them with new ones.

Comment: tempSourecode.get(tempSourecode.size()-1).concat(" " + iterator.next()); I already tried this. It is not working

Comment: @MarounMaroun thanks. I got it working. :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that strings are immutable, so when you do

```
x.get(x.size() - 1).concat("s");
```

you merely create a *new* string with appended "s", but you do not change the string in the list. Instead, you have to replace the element at that position with the new string:

```
    List<String> x = Arrays.asList("cow", "cat", "dog");
    x.set(x.size() - 1, x.get(x.size() - 1) + "s"); // or concat, if you prefer
    System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Yeah i forgot that strings are immutable. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment, you can try the following:

```
String old = tempSourecode.get(tempSourecode.size()-1)
tempSourecode.set(tempSourecode.size()-1, old + "s");
```

Comment: Yeah i forgot that strings are immutable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the following:

```
int index = x.size()-1;
String lastElement = x.remove(index);
x.add(lastElement + "s");
```

This is a bit long winded to show each step, but you could refactor this down to something simpler.

Comment: Yeah i forgot that strings are immutable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this!

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("cow");
list.add("cat");
list.add("dog");
list.set((list.size()-1),list.get(list.size()-1).concat("s"));
```

Comment: This does _not_ change the values in the list!

Comment: @tobias_k - I had misinterpreted the question previously. Fixed my answer, now. Thanks for the heads up. Cheers!